# How can you LEFT JOIN a table to a table being joined ON a sub-select?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I am using the following query to join tables together and it seems to be working although I can't really understand why:

```
    SELECT
        listing.name,
        biggestLot.price,
    FROM Listings listing
    LEFT JOIN Lots biggestLot ON biggestLot.lotNumber = (
            SELECT lotNumber
            FROM Lots
            WHERE lotNumber IN
                (
                    SELECT lotNumber
                    FROM Listings listingInner
                    WHERE listingInner.listingNumber = listing.listingNumber
                )
            ORDER BY size DESC
            LIMIT 1
    )
    GROUP BY listing.listingNumber
```

The context is that each "Listing" is associated with one or more "Lots" through a "lotNumber" field. The tables aren't normalized; i.e. for any given Listing, there may be one or more rows in the "Listings" table that have duplicate values for all fields except for "lotNumber". The intent of the above query is to find the price of the biggest Lot associated with each Listing.

The inner `SELECT` is getting the largest Lot for a given Listing and I understand how that works. What I don't understand is how the `LEFT JOIN` merges the `biggestLot` result with the outer `SELECT` Listings query. I'm not specifying an `ON` field to combine the two tables so how does it know how to combine the results?

Comment: The subquery is correlated with `WHERE listingInner.listingNumber = listing.listingNumber`

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate. For further help, please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: It's not clear what you don't understand. How left join & inner join work are faqs. ON does not "combine" rows. A join does a cross join, then resulting rows satisfying a on/using are kept, then left/right/full join adds via UNION ALL any unmatched right/left/both table rows extended by nulls. A select returns a table, find out what a scalar subquery is. Write a minimal  query that shows what you don't understand (apparently not needing anything to do with your application) & give a [mre] that includes how you are stuck reading authoritative documentation. Say what you expect & why.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the attempts at help everyone. I think I'm just in over my head at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You could can use window functions along with the `JOIN`:

```
SELECT l.name, lo.price,
FROM Listings l LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT lo.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARITION BY lo.lotNumber ORDER BY lo.size DESC) as seqnum
      FROM Lots lo
     ) lo
     USING (lotNmber);
```